# How to read xml and stored in list?

Tags: c#, xml

How can I read xml format look like this? and I want to get the value and store in List.
this is my XML format.

this is my class

```
public string itemName {get;set;}
public string itemOriginalPath{get;set;}
```

this is my xml.

```
<images>
   <image>
      <itemName>codev_new_logo.jpg</itemName>
      <itemOriginalPath>c:\users\sseno\desktop\sean\codev_new_logo.jpg</itemOriginalPath>
   </image>
   <image>
      <itemName>codev_new_logo_1.jpg</itemName>
      <itemOriginalPath>c:\users\sseno\desktop\sean\codev_new_logo_1.jpg</itemOriginalPath>
  </image>
</images>
```

please help.

---

Thank you @lazyberezovsky
I added 
     xdoc.Elements("images").Elements("image")

Comment: you can use DataSet to store xml content and then convert to List

Comment: Generally, somehow overlooked this time, you should show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). "This is my class" - "this is my xml" - please help usually doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var images = from i in xdoc.Root.Elements("image")
             select new Image {
                itemName = (string)i.Element("itemName"),
                itemOriginalPath = (string)i.Element("itemOriginalPath")
             };
```

This query will return `IEnumerable<Image>`. If you want to have `List<Image>` then simply apply `.ToList()` on query results.

BTW in C# we use PascalNames for properties.

Comment: It's returning 0 count, but this is so close I need.

Comment: Thank you I got it I just added  xdoc.Elements("images").Elements("image")

Comment: @SeanPogz looks like you missed `Root` part of query